# GetStream Laravel - Cannot batchadd to notification

Tags: laravel-5.4, getstream-io

I can't seem to use the batcher to copy an activity to notifications.  I read from the docs
that there is a 100 limit to the TO field for copying activities, so i tried out using the batcher.  but it does'nt seem to work.  did I miss out something on the docs or on my code?  if so, how do I get over the 100 limit?

```
$evtConvMention = array();
$evtConvMention[] = "event:{$event->id}";
$evtConvMention[] = "notification:1";
$evtConvMention[] = "notification:2";

$batcher = FeedManager::getClient()->batcher();
$batcher->addToMany([
  "actor"      => "App\User:{$user->id}",
  "verb"       => "eventpost",
  "object"     => "App\EventConversation:{$post->id}",
  "foreign_id" => "App\EventConversation:{$post->id}"
], $evtConvMention);
```

Comment: When you say `it doesn't seem to work` what result are you getting? Is it throwing an error? Can we see the error message? How many feeds are you adding to `$evtConvMention`?

Comment: @iandouglas, i want the activity to show up in the event feed and also in the notification feed for (users) 1 and 2.  i don't get an error, but the TO field shows up blank on the Explorer, and on my app, users 1 and 2 also do not get the notification.

Answer (score 0):

The `addToMany()` call will have a similar limit. While I look into the PHP library a little more, it might be easier to use the `To` field in the activity payload itself.

```
$feed = FeedManager::getClient()->feed("event", $event->id);
$now = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
$data = [
    "actor"      => "App\User:{$user->id}",
    "verb"       => "eventpost",
    "object"     => "App\EventConversation:{$post->id}",
    "foreign_id" => "App\EventConversation:{$post->id}",
    "time"       => $now
];
$feed->addActivity($data);
```

We also HIGHLY recommend sending your own `foreign_id` and `time` fields in the payload as well (I've added an idea for the `$now` value in the code above, otherwise every feed will get its own unique record, which are a limited resource on your account.

If you have more than 100 notification feeds to write this into, it might be better to have the notification feeds for those users 'follow' the event feed. Then you don't need to use the `to` field at all.